# Issue On Running ASP.NET Core on Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to make a ASP.Net Core using MS VS Code. I have  Class like this and I already add the `using System.Collections.Generic;` to the refrences

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace App.Models
{
    public class Event
    {
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public static List GetSampleEvents()
        {
            List events = new List() {
                                        new Event{
                                        EventID = 1,
                                        StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/09"),
                                        EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/09")
                                                   },
                                        new Event{
                                        EventID = 2,
                                        StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/09"),
                                        EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/09")                      
                                        }
                                        };
                                        return events;

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error

> Using the generic type 'List' requires 1 type arguments
>   [netcoreapp1.0]

[image]

the project.json looks like

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [
        "appsettings.json"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

can you please let me know whay this is happening?
**

> Update

**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AppWebsite.Models;

namespace App.Models
{
    public class AppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet Events { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity().HasKey(m => m.Id);
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string constr = Utility.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");
            string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            constr = constr.Replace("=", "=" + path + "\\");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(constr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe List<Event>?

Comment: Thanks Alex but how about the `DbSet` in `DbContext` class?  I mean I am getting exactky same error at ` public DbSet Events { get; set; }`

Comment: where is your DbContext? please post it.

Comment: I just updated the post with `appContext` class, thanks

Comment: I think you should use DbSet<Event>

Comment: and constructor: public AppContext (DbContextOptions<AppContext > options) : base(options)
        {
        }

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

Answer (score 0):

problem is in this line

`List events = new List()`

in the namespace **System.Collections.Generic** we only have a generic version of **List<T>** so compiler is expecting to define a Type argument .So we should change from List to List<T>

```
 public static List<Event> GetSampleEvents()
    {

        List<Event> events = new List<Event>() {
                                    new Event{
                                    EventID = 1,
                                    StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/09"),
                                    EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/09")
                                               },
                                    new Event{
                                    EventID = 2,
                                    StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/09"),
                                    EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/09")                      
                                    }
                                    };
                                    return events;

    }
```